# Jackson Json accesing JsonNode property name

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a schema like this:

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
  "id" : "urn:jsonschema:com:vlashel:dto:UserDto",
  "description" : "this is the top description",
  "title" : "this is the top title",
  "properties" : {
    "number" : {
      "type" : "integer"
      "required" : true
    },
    "password" : {
      "type" : "string"
      "required" : true

    }
}
```

I have the following code that converts this shcema draft 3 to draft 4 by removing "required", I want to collect nodes property names that have 'requred' in them. How do I do that? I don't see methods for this..

```
             JsonNode jsonNode = jsonNodeIterator.next();
            ObjectNode element;
            if (jsonNode instanceof ObjectNode) {
                element = (ObjectNode) jsonNode;
                element.remove("required");
               String propertyName = element.getPropertyName(); //I'm looking for this kind of method.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which property? An `ObjectNode` is an  object with multiple properties. You could iterate over them using `Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> getFields()` but I'm not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: this is actually what I was loooking for) thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all of the nodes that have that property by using the [`List<JsonNode> findParents(String fieldName)`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.html#findParents%28java.lang.String%29), which does that this for you. From the docs:

> Method for finding a JSON Object that contains specified field, within
>   this node or its descendants. If no matching field is found in this
>   node or its descendants, returns null.

I made a quick example but had to add a few characters to the JSON blob you posted as it is missing some commas and a bracket and can't be read by the ObjectMapper. It is as simple as this:

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(SCHEMA);
List<JsonNode> required = root.findParents("required");
for (JsonNode node: required) {
    Object prettyOutput = mapper.readValue(node, Object.class);
    System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(prettyOutput));
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "type" : "integer",
  "required" : true
}
{
  "type" : "string",
  "required" : true
}
```